# NTP server, port not open

Tags: windows, port, time, ntp, ntpd

So, I'm trying to install an NTP server on this Windows 10 Home computer.  I've tried [various tutorials](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-configure-ntp-server-in-windows-server/) to enable w32time's server mode, and then when that failed I eventually installed [Meinberg NTP](https://www.meinbergglobal.com/english/sw/ntp.htm), to no avail.  So here's the thing: the services claim they are working properly, but the NTP port (123) remains closed.  I have turned off the firewall.  I have no other security software installed that I know of.  Here's a log:  (Note that the service stops and starts in the middle of the logfile because I rebooted the computer.)

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\NTP>cat log\log.log
11 Jun 15:30:36 ntpd[3228]: ntpd 4.2.8p15-o Jun 25 14:45:34 (UTC+02:00) 2020  (2): Starting
11 Jun 15:30:36 ntpd[3228]: Command line: C:\Program Files (x86)\NTP\bin\ntpd.exe -U 3 -M -g -c C:\Program Files (x86)\NTP\etc\ntp.conf -l C:\Program Files (x86)\NTP\log\log.log
11 Jun 15:30:36 ntpd[3228]: ----------------------------------------------------
11 Jun 15:30:36 ntpd[3228]: ntp-4 is maintained by Network Time Foundation,
11 Jun 15:30:36 ntpd[3228]: Inc. (NTF), a non-profit 501(c)(3) public-benefit
11 Jun 15:30:36 ntpd[3228]: corporation.  Support and training for ntp-4 are
11 Jun 15:30:36 ntpd[3228]: available at https://www.nwtime.org/support
11 Jun 15:30:36 ntpd[3228]: ----------------------------------------------------
11 Jun 15:30:36 ntpd[3228]: Raised to realtime priority class
11 Jun 15:30:36 ntpd[3228]: Clock interrupt period 15.625 msec
11 Jun 15:30:36 ntpd[3228]: Performance counter frequency 10.000 MHz
11 Jun 15:30:36 ntpd[3228]: proto: precision = 0.100 usec (-23)
11 Jun 15:30:36 ntpd[3228]: basedate set to 2020-06-18
11 Jun 15:30:36 ntpd[3228]: gps base set to 2020-06-21 (week 2111)
11 Jun 15:30:36 ntpd[3228]: Listen and drop on 0 v6wildcard [::]:123
11 Jun 15:30:36 ntpd[3228]: Listen and drop on 1 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0:123
11 Jun 15:30:36 ntpd[3228]: Listen normally on 2 Wi-Fi [fe80::c99b:cdce:96ea:21bf%14]:123
11 Jun 15:30:36 ntpd[3228]: Listen normally on 3 Wi-Fi 192.168.1.153:123
11 Jun 15:30:36 ntpd[3228]: Listen normally on 4 Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1 [::1]:123
11 Jun 15:30:36 ntpd[3228]: Listen normally on 5 Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1 127.0.0.1:123
11 Jun 15:34:13 ntpd[3228]: SCM requests stop (system shutdown)
11 Jun 15:34:13 ntpd[3228]: ntservice: The Network Time Protocol Service is stopping.
11 Jun 15:34:36 ntpd[4696]: ntpd 4.2.8p15-o Jun 25 14:45:34 (UTC+02:00) 2020  (2): Starting
11 Jun 15:34:36 ntpd[4696]: Command line: C:\Program Files (x86)\NTP\bin\ntpd.exe -U 3 -M -g -c C:\Program Files (x86)\NTP\etc\ntp.conf -l C:\Program Files (x86)\NTP\log\log.log
11 Jun 15:34:36 ntpd[4696]: ----------------------------------------------------
11 Jun 15:34:36 ntpd[4696]: ntp-4 is maintained by Network Time Foundation,
11 Jun 15:34:36 ntpd[4696]: Inc. (NTF), a non-profit 501(c)(3) public-benefit
11 Jun 15:34:36 ntpd[4696]: corporation.  Support and training for ntp-4 are
11 Jun 15:34:36 ntpd[4696]: available at https://www.nwtime.org/support
11 Jun 15:34:36 ntpd[4696]: ----------------------------------------------------
11 Jun 15:34:36 ntpd[4696]: Raised to realtime priority class
11 Jun 15:34:36 ntpd[4696]: Clock interrupt period 15.625 msec
11 Jun 15:34:36 ntpd[4696]: Performance counter frequency 10.000 MHz
11 Jun 15:34:36 ntpd[4696]: proto: precision = 0.200 usec (-22)
11 Jun 15:34:36 ntpd[4696]: basedate set to 2020-06-18
11 Jun 15:34:36 ntpd[4696]: gps base set to 2020-06-21 (week 2111)
11 Jun 15:34:36 ntpd[4696]: Listen and drop on 0 v6wildcard [::]:123
11 Jun 15:34:36 ntpd[4696]: Listen and drop on 1 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0:123
11 Jun 15:34:36 ntpd[4696]: Listen normally on 2 Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1 [::1]:123
11 Jun 15:34:36 ntpd[4696]: Listen normally on 3 Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1 127.0.0.1:123
11 Jun 15:34:42 ntpd[4696]: Listen normally on 4 Wi-Fi [fe80::c99b:cdce:96ea:21bf%14]:123
11 Jun 15:34:42 ntpd[4696]: Listen normally on 5 Wi-Fi 192.168.1.153:123

C:\Program Files (x86)\NTP>nmap -p 123 localhost
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-06-11 15:35 Central Daylight Time
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): ::1

PORT    STATE  SERVICE
123/tcp closed ntp

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.19 seconds

C:\Program Files (x86)\NTP>nmap -p 123 127.0.0.1
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-06-11 15:35 Central Daylight Time
Nmap scan report for 127.0.0.1
Host is up (0.00s latency).

PORT    STATE  SERVICE
123/tcp closed ntp

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.17 seconds

C:\Program Files (x86)\NTP>nmap -p 123 192.168.1.153
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-06-11 15:35 Central Daylight Time
Nmap scan report for DESKTOP-CL2NMV9.lan (192.168.1.153)
Host is up (0.00s latency).

PORT    STATE  SERVICE
123/tcp closed ntp

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.19 seconds

C:\Program Files (x86)\NTP>
```

The service claims to listen on port 123, at many addresses, and  `netstat -abn` agrees that ntpd.exe IS listening on 123 at many addresses, but nmap conversely says that 123 is closed on every local-pointing address I try.  Can anybody explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, nmap tests TCP ports. The NTP protocol uses *only* UDP, and the ntpd service only sets up UDP sockets, not TCP.

Those do not interact in any way – probing the TCP port 123 tells you absolutely nothing about what's listening on UDP port 123, nor the other way around.

---

Additionally, even though you can ask nmap to scan UDP, it won't work as reliably as TCP.

In TCP, you can already tell that a port is definitely "open" vs "closed" if you can establish a connection at TCP level, *before* getting to speak the application-layer protocol. That is, either you receive an affirmative handshake packet (the SYN-ACK), or negative (RST), or nothing at all, but you learn this from TCP itself. (Nmap's `--reason` option would show this in more detail.)

In UDP, on the other hand, there is no separate connection establishment – you send any packet and it *directly* goes to the service in question. So if you send an NTP packet and receive a response, you know for sure that the port is "open" in all senses. But if you send something that is *not* an NTP packet but only a generic probe, then the service might choose to simply not reply!

So with UDP you *cannot* tell the difference between "no reply because the listener chose to ignore your garbage packet" versus "no reply because there *is* nothing listening"<sup>1</sup> versus "no reply because the firewall dropped the packet before it reached the listener".

To determine whether a UDP socket exists, use `netstat`; and to determine whether the socket responds *to valid NTP queries* use an actual NTP client (such as `ntpdate -q`, `sntp`, or `w32tm /monitor`).

<sup>1</sup> (In theory, if there was nothing listening to a UDP port, you would normally receive an ICMP "Port Unreachable" error. In practice, Windows Firewall operates in so-called "stealth mode" where ports without a listener will not produce any response at all, neither RST for TCP nor ICMP for UDP, *even if* the port is allowed by rules. If you want, this can be [disabled](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/disable-stealth-mode).)